# Array not compiling after 12 elements?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm trying to create an array, but my program will not compile if I have more than 12 elements in the array. For example:

```
PROGRAM dprime
REAL, DIMENSION(12) :: array
array = (/50.0,52.0,54.0,56.0,58.0,60.0,62.0,64.0,66.0,68.0,70.0,72.0/)
END PROGRAM dprime
```

Now, if I change it to `DIMENSION(13)` and add another element after `72.0,` I get the following error:

> Error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one
>   of: , (/ : /).

This code will not compile:

```
PROGRAM dprime
REAL, DIMENSION(13) :: array
array =(/50.0,52.0,54.0,56.0,58.0,60.0,62.0,64.0,66.0,68.0,70.0,72.0,74.0/)
END PROGRAM
```

Where could there be an error?

Comment: Learn how to divide lines in Fortran. It is different in fixed form and in free form. It is actually strange that you manage to use exactly 72 characters, because first 6 columns should have special meaning in fixed form. What is the extension of your source file? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I am not using a source file, the array is in the program itself. I'm using the Intel ifort compiler.

Comment: I am asking where do you store the text of the program. That is called "source file". Is it .f90 .f .for or what is it? Which options do you use when compiling? Or how do you compile? Do you press some button or what do you do?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably beyond the allowed line length.

For gfortran, add the option `-ffree-line-length-none` to the command line.

EDIT:

Most probably, just rename your file to `*.f90` and you'll be set with most compilers, including ifort that you are using. This strategy has a limit: beyond 132 characters you must use continuation lines with the character `&` at the end of a line.

Comment: Also: in fortran 90+, the allowed line length is larger (132 characters), it will be autodetected by most compilers if you name your files `*.f90`.

Comment: I think the cause is true, but I wouldn't offer this as the first or only solution.

Comment: I avoid such compiler directives as it will force you to figure out the directive every time you encounter a new compiler.  Especially if using fixed form for some reason, stick to the standard form.

Comment: It is still a strange advice to just rename files. Fixed and free form are quite different! What about comments? Notice also, that his line has exactly 72 characters. Normally, one would expect 72 characters **including leading spaces**. I would have closed it as a duplicate of many other line too long question, but I still don't know what is going on.

Comment: I counted 75 after copy-pasting. I am under the impression that most compiler will identify `.f90` files as free-form and `.f` as fixed-form. So, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: 72 is the working code. That is too much already for a fixed-form file. Why a bad idea? Because they are not compatible. You cannot just take a fixed form code and compile it as free form code. Unless some special care was done when writing the code.

Comment: ifort has the -132 compiler switch to allow 132 characters. the -free and -fixed can be used with -132 but it is redundant for -free.