# Several errors when compiling

Tags: fortran

This is part of the code I am using

```
      module bodyforce

      use shared_module

      contains
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

      subroutine openforcingprofile(fx,fy,fz)

c      integer   p1(0:NYforc),p2(0:NYforc),posy1,posy2
      complex*8  :: FXA(0:NY+1,1),FYA(0:NY+1),FZA(0:NY+1),ii,
     &              FXB(0:NY+1),FYB(0:NY+1),FZB(0:NY+1),
     &              FXB(0:NY+1),FYB(0:NY+1),FZB(0:NY+1),
     &              FX(0:NY+1),FY(0:NY+1),FZ(0:NY+1)
      real*8  :: k11real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k13real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k21real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k23real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k31real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k33real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k12real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k22real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k32real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)
c
      real*8  :: k11imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k13imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k21imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k23imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k31imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k33imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     &           k12imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k22imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k32imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)
      complex*16 k11(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k13(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     & k21(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k23(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     & k31(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k33(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),
     & k12(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k22(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k32(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)

      ii=sqrt(cmplx(-1.d0,0))

CCCCCCCCC READ SUBMATRICES



      OPEN (91,file= 'inf/matrix_re.dat',form='formatted',status='old')   
      OPEN (92,file= 'inf/matrix_im.dat',form='formatted',status='old')   

       do i=0,NY_INT-1
           READ(91,*) k11real(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       READ(92,*) k11imag(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       end do
```

I get a bunch of errors comprising the following:

```
bodyforce.f(19): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ) , : ] /)
     &           k32real(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)
-----------------------------------------------^
bodyforce.f(24): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ) , : ] /)
     &           k12imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k22imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k32imag(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
bodyforce.f(28): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ) ,
     & k12(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k22(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1),k32(0:NY_INT-1,0:NY_INT-1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
bodyforce.f(73): error #5082: Syntax error, found ':' when expecting one of: )
           READ(91,*) k31real((i,0:NY_INT-1)
----------------------------------^
bodyforce.f(74): error #5082: Syntax error, found ':' when expecting one of: )
           READ(92,*) k31imag((i,0:NY_INT-1)
----------------------------------^
bodyforce.f(89): error #5149: Illegal character in statement label field  [D]
    DO JJ=JSTART,JEND
----^
bodyforce.f(89): error #5082: Syntax error, found ',' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;
    DO JJ=JSTART,JEND
----------------^
```

I strongly believe some of them are due to the misuse of blank lines and spaces, which I don't know quite well in FORTRAN. Could you give me an insight? Apparently, there are also some other syntax errors.

Comment: Welcome. Please Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please find some title for your question that describes the actual problem. Almost every question here is about errors when compiling or running.

Comment: We need to know what is the file extension of your code, how are you compiling it. Please post the exact compilation command including all flags. It looks like you are treating the source as fixed form, but it is actually free form or something like that.

Comment: Note that you are declaring `FXB` twice. Please post a [mcve]that we can try. We do not have the shared module.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, Vladimir F. I use
source /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/073/bin/ifortvars.sh intel64
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/intel/binexi
and the file extension is .f

Comment: Probable fixed form line length issue - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724248/array-not-compiling-after-12-elements

Comment: note this is absolutely fixed form. You can not treat it as free by changing the extension, flags , etc. (suggested in the linked answer)  It looks like two lines are too long (The one beginning `&           k12imag` is obviously way too long)

Comment: That will be it. Not a very good duplicate target though.

Comment: @agentp not what?

Comment: I'd suggest converting the source code to free (vs fixed) format through findent http://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/content/findent/introduction or a similar recent Fortran source code reformatter. You're already using F90-later so compatibility isn't an issue, plus it'll free up some line space and may fix your issue.

Comment: Sorted. Thank you!